# How to configure apple pay payment with authorize.net payment method in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, authorize.net, apple-pay

How can implement the apple pay payment method with the authorize.net payment method? Can anyone tell me how to implement it in Magento 2?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Authorized.Net is Deprecated Since Magento Version 2.3, you can use Braintree to let your customer pay through applepay. otherwise you have to go for a thirdparty extension.